# Why isn't my 3D Model Loading in three.js using the glTF loader?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, cors, xmlhttprequest

I'm loading an object into three.js for the first time. I have the object downloaded on my computer. The three.js library is connected to my html document as well as the glTF loader. But when I go to run the code I keep receiving this error:

> three_js_library.js:713 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Firstname%20Lastname/Desktop/neuron.glb' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

So I figure it's having some trouble loading my 3d model because of the CORS policy. I've tried [reading the CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and what that is, but it didn't help me solve my problem of having the 3d model show on the screen without errors.

Then I tried downloading a [CORS everywhere extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/) for the firefox browser that I learned of from a [forum](https://github.com/dwyl/faster/issues/54) about a similar issue, but that did not produce the desired result. It returned this error on Firefox which I think is the same one I got from google:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/Firstname%20Lastname/Desktop/neuron.glb. >>(Reason: CORS request not http).

I just want the 3D model to be loaded successfully on the screen.

If anyone has a solution as to what I am doing wrong and how I can get my model to load on the screen, that would very much appreciated.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="three_js_library.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src='MS_Interactive_Sim.js'>    </script>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load( 'neuron.glb', function ( gltf ) {
scene.add( gltf.scene );
}, undefined, function ( error ) {
console.error( error );
} );
const animate =()=>{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because browsers have a same-origin policy security restriction. There are a few solutions as described [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally). I suggest that you run your files from a local server, such as [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/).

Comment: I just learned about web servers that can be used like MAMP and XXAMP. It turns out I can also create a local server with node.js and other languages.